# Why wont javascript get values of php generated html?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

im using ajax to query my mysql to my database.
But im stock at issue with my php generated html form input - javascript/jquery will simply not pick up the value. From normal html is no issue of course.

php (works fine, all echos are good)

```
<?php
function getAge() {
    $age = "<select name='age'>";
    $result = $mysqli->query("select * from ages");
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        $age.="<option value=" . $row[0] . ">". $row[1] ."</option>";
    }
    $age.="</select>";

    return $age;
}
?>
```

html

```
<form id="myform">
   <input name='name' value='Nick'>
   <input name='sport' value='Football'>
   <?php echo getAge(); ?>
   <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

javascript

```
$("form#myform").on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var json = {}
    $.each(this.elements, function(){
        json[this.name] = this.value || '';
    });
}
```

Everything works well except it wont get the value of the `<select>`. If i make a normal html select it works.. ?!
Also anybody know how to delete the submit button from the json object? :-)

Comment: did you try to serialize the form? Have a look at [Jquery Form Serialization](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: What's the generated HTML? Put in some `console.debug();` and trace down the issue.

Comment: There is no difference between a normal html select and a php generated html select. Whatever the problem is, it is unlikely to have anything to do with the PHP.

Comment: Do you get  proper value in `$age`

Comment: yes i do get proper value

Comment: @Andriano why do normal select in html <select> work?

Comment: What value do you get in `$age`?

Comment: @MissChetanGawai i think that is OP's select tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any dynamically generated HTML will not have the events applied to them, as those events are applied on page load. So if you apply the events to the document, you will be able to pull values from dynamically generated html. Like so:

```
var json = {};
$(document).on('submit', 'form#myform', function(e){
   $('*', this).each(function(){    
        json[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
   });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this makes sense! but the function wont fire now?

Comment: Had a typo, forgot a comma.

Comment: i did see that, still nothing :)

Comment: made a quick change, see if that gives you any output in the console.

Comment: OH i does! seems like i get the value!

Comment: because after applying the event to the overall document, we loop through all children of the form and capture their values.

Comment: but how come javascript can see the values then?

Comment: Can or cant? Javascript and jQuery both can see the values as long as it is applied to the document. The document exist on page load, where as your generated html doesn't.

Comment: what a perfect input @wrxsti - worked like a champ. and i could even add: delete json["undefined"] to get rid of the button input!

Answer (score 1):

change this line:

```
$age.="<option value=" . $row[0] . ">". $row[1] ."</option>";
```

to this:

```
$age.="<option value='" . $row[0] . "'>". $row[1] ."</option>";
   //----------------^---------------^------put quotes
```

---

And i think you can make use of [`.serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) which does the same you want but in a different way like multiple objects with multiple `[{ name : value}]` pairs:

```
$(function(){  //<-----put this block too
   $("form#myform").on('submit', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var json = $(this).serializeArray();
   });    //<----checkout the closing
}); //<---doc ready closed.
```

Comment: ill give that a shot! in debugger i do have quotes around my value i DOM.

Comment: .serializeArray() wont get the select value aswell

Comment: I'm not sure about, but `var json = {}` makes the variable local scope inside the function? Change it to `json = {}`.

Comment: @MacLuc as i see your question your jquery code is missing the closing of click event, see if that might be the issue and is it wrapped in `doc ready` block. Also lookout for any js errors in your browser's console.

Comment: its wrapped in doc ready and i did close it right in production code :)

Comment: @MacLuc okay! see if your form and form elems are generated dynamically then you have to delegate the event to the closest static parent or `document` itself.